# Unable to update listbox from database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, listbox, itemssource

In my application I have listBox and its items source is ObservableCollection, but when I add data, this listBox won't update. In constructor i use:
`listBoxPersons.ItemsSource = UserContacts;`
and user UserContacts is static ObservableCollection, which is initialised from database and when I open the programm, it shows correct data. But when I add new item into database and in same time using same code `listBoxPersons.ItemsSource = UserContacts;`, then listBox won't display added item. But when I logout and login again to my application, it displays my added items.

Answer (score 1):

You literally said add new item into the database.  You need to also add the item to the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is with the `static` ObservableCollection. 
Try it with a non-static collection.

Comment: Using non-static didn't fix my problem. Also I find that, when I use non static, it won't display added item, but when I update existing item in listbox, these changes are displayed.